# SQL Server data type

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Please view for example.

[image]

I don't understand `SQL Server` data types. It has a `nvarchar` data type column.

I want to import that data in `MySql`.

What is this this column. `Md5` or `Base64` ?

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: The data looks like an 128-bit hash.

Comment: The column appears to contain GUIDs/UUIDs - It's fairly common to format such values into groups of 8,4,4,4,12 hex characters, separated by dashes.

Comment: Looks like GUIDS are being stored in a unicode string (nvarchar) field. Typically, a GUID would be stored as a uniqueidentifier type.

Answer (score 2):

As per msdn variable-length Unicode string data. `n` defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. `max` indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for `nvarchar` are `national char varying` and `national character varying`.

So it's a plain string datatype with Unicode support. I hope now it will be easy for you to find the matching datatype in MySQL.